# Twitter Bootstrap Carousel Random load 5 items

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following Twitter bootstrap carousel with 20 items, how can I randomly only load 5 of the items on load? I found another script that hid the items however this wouldnt work due to it being a slideshow.

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
<!-- Carousel items -->
<div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="active item"><img src="img/slider/1.jpg"></div>
<div class="item"><img src="img/slider/2.jpg"></div>
<div class="item"><img src="img/slider/3.jpg"></div>
<div class="item"><img src="img/slider/4.jpg"></div>
<div class="item"><img src="img/slider/5.jpg"></div>
</div>
<!-- Carousel nav -->
<a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
<a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
</div></div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: 8000
    })
    });
   </script>
```

Comment: i would do it server side thereby only loading 5 images rather than all 20

Comment: I think server side might be the answer, but was hoping it could be done just with jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do some pure `JS` and then `JQuery` on this one:

I will show two options.

The first one will generate 5 random numbers and then
change `src` attribute of `img` element using those random numbers
as images for the carousel, like:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $('.carousel').carousel({
 interval: 8000
 });

 var arr = []; // array for images to display
 while(arr.length<5) // Get random numbers from 1 to 20 up to 5 in length
 {
   var rnd = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 20); // Generate random numbers 1 to 20
   if (arr.indexOf(rnd)<0) // Check if it is not in Array already
   {
      arr.push(rnd); // Add to array if random number not in array
   }
 }

var idx=0; // index for the image to display
$('.carousel img').each(function()
 {
    // change the src in img to randomly generated numbers
    $(this).attr('src','img/slider/'+arr[idx]+'.jpg'); 
    idx++;
 });
</script>
```

The second one is to put all 20 images before loading.
However, upon loading hide them. Then randomly picks up 5 numbers
from 1 to 20. And then unhide or show those 5 random numbers as
part of the carousel. Like the one below.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $('.carousel').carousel({
 interval: 8000
 });

 // Hide all img under carousel class
 $('.carousel img').each(function()
 {
   $(this).hide(); 
 });

 var arr = []; // array for images to display
 while(arr.length<5) // Get random numbers from 1 to 20 up to 5 in length
 {
   var rnd = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 20); // Generate random numbers 1 to 20
   if (arr.indexOf(rnd)<0) // Check if it is not in Array already
   {
      arr.push(rnd); // Add to array if random number not in array
   }
 }

var idx=1;
$('.carousel img').each(function()
 {
  if (arr.indexOf(idx)>=0) // if it matches the generated number generated earlier
   {
     $(this).show(); // show the image hidden earlier
    }
  idx++; // increment index
});
</script>
```

**Caveat**: This is untested so change it according to your own need or correct
errors if any.

However, I have made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t8ZH3/2) using `li` element instead of images
because I don't have online images that I could use.

Comment: This would only change to order. There are 20 items and I only need 5 to be loaded

Comment: @MattHull Are the images sequential in name as what you have shown in your post? And as Ryan suggested this is very doable in server side (e.g. php, asp) but client-side a little bit extra work. By the way what is your server side scripting language?

Comment: yes, the images would be named 1-20 and hopefully load 5 random slides. Scripting would be PHP but I had hoped to do this with jquery

Comment: @MattHull Glad to be of help. GOD bless and Happy coding!